# Dynamically add class methods during class definition

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a bunch of methods somewhere, already defined.  I want a class to just be a collection of those methods.

```
def _a(self):
  pass

def _b(self):
  pass

@decorated()
class MyClass(object):
  a = _a
  b = _b
```

The decorator is written by someone else, and it does some analysis on the class immediately.

What I want is to stick those methods on the class, but they need to be on there before the decorator does its magic.

```
methods = { 'a': _a, 'b': _b }

@decorated(...)
class MyClass(object):
  for name, impl in methods
    # What goes here?
```

How can I do this.  I assume it's some form of setattr(), but how do I get the target when it's the class I'm currently building?

### Update

Current experiment is:

```
def merged(method_dict):
  def _impl(cls):
    for name, impl in method_dict.iteritems():
      setattr(cls, name, impl)
    return cls

  return _impl

@decorated(...)
@merged(methods)
class MyClass(object):
  c = _c
  pass
```

The `decorated` decorator is reporting that it sees `c`, but not `a` or `b`

Comment: Or just use the decorator when you're ready - `MyClass = decorator()(MyClass)`, rather than using the `@` syntax.

Comment: Why is your set of methods not implemented as a base class?

Comment: Or use mixins if you want the methods to be handled individually.

Comment: @Monkey There are going to be a variety of classes that pick and choose the methods.  I could do base classes, but the dividing lines aren't particularly clear.  I tried mixins, and the decorator didn't pick up the methods, not clear why.

Comment: Using a decorator with the `@` syntax isn't working, not clear why.  Is there anything I might need to do special to be able to use the result of that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that as soon as your class is defined, it is immediately getting decorated, as you use the `@` syntax. Some alternatives are to go the way [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025567/dynamically-add-class-methods-during-class-definition#comment53873599_33025567) and  [Ashwini Chaudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025567/dynamically-add-class-methods-during-class-definition#comment53873576_33025567) suggested.

Also, another way you can do the thing, is wrapping the decorator into your custom one, where you will do your stuff and then only, manually decorate with the provided one, like this:

```
def your_decorator(func):
    # your stuff
    return decorated(func)

@your_decorator
class MyClass():
    # ...
```

Comment: I'm experimenting with the other decorator right now, updated question with details.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with what jonrsharpe suggested in the comments section: Instead of decorating the class using the `@` syntax, which decorates the class immediately after it's created, you should decorate it manually afterwards:

```
class MyClass:
    pass

def _method_to_add_later(self):
    pass

MyClass.method_to_add_later = _method_to_add_later

MyClass = decorated(...)(MyClass)
```

Answer (score -1):

For example, may be right

```
def decorator(fn):
    def _fn(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Decorator"
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return _fn


@decorator
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print "Init"

def _a():
    print "a"

def _b():
    print "b"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    methods = { 'a': _a, 'b': _b }
    my = decorator(MyClass())
    for name in methods:
        setattr(my, name, methods[name])
    my.a()
    my.b()
```

Out:

```
Decorator
Init
a
b
```

Comment: This adds the methods after the decorator is applied.  Also, the decorator is applied twice.  Also, the methods are added to the instance of `my`, not the class itself.